# Apple maps searching doesnt work in ios objective-c?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to open apple map in my app. I wrote the function below. The maps opens but it doesnt search address. What did I miss?

```
  + (void)openMap:(NSString*)address
    {
        Class mapItemClass = [MKMapItem class];
        if (mapItemClass && [mapItemClass respondsToSelector:@selector(openMapsWithItems:launchOptions:)]) {
            MKPlacemark* placemark = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:kCLLocationCoordinate2DInvalid
                                                           addressDictionary:nil];
            MKMapItem* mapItem = [[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:placemark];
            [mapItem setName:address];
            [mapItem openInMapsWithLaunchOptions:nil];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

It is not clear what you expect. Your job is to give your placemark a coordinate. You did not (you used `kCLLocationCoordinate2DInvalid`). So the Maps app literally doesn't know where to go.

If, on the other hand, your purpose is to turn an address into a coordinate, you could be using CLGeocoder. Here's [an example in Objective-C](http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch34.html#_geocoding).

Comment: Can't I use map without give a coordinate?

Comment: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch34.html#_communicating_with_the_maps_app

Comment: But I want to search and locate a place.

Comment: My app doesnt contain map component. It opens apple maps app externally.

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide proper latitude and longitude to drop the pin and you can you like this below.

```
func openMapForPlace() {
    let regionDistance: CLLocationDistance = 10000000
    let coordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(40, 0)
    let regionSpan = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(coordinates, regionDistance, regionDistance)
    let options = [
        MKLaunchOptionsMapCenterKey: NSValue(MKCoordinate: regionSpan.center),
        MKLaunchOptionsMapSpanKey: NSValue(MKCoordinateSpan: regionSpan.span)
    ]

    let placemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: coordinates, addressDictionary: nil)
    let mapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: placemark)
    mapItem.name = "Test"

    MKMapItem.openMapsWithItems([mapItem], launchOptions: options)
}
```

**For Objective C:**

```
    CLLocationDistance regionDistance = 100000;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(40, 0);
    MKCoordinateRegion regionSpan = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(coordinates, regionDistance, regionDistance);


    MKPlacemark *placeMark = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:coordinates addressDictionary:nil];
    MKMapItem *mapItem = [[MKMapItem alloc]initWithPlacemark: placeMark];
    mapItem.name = @"Test";
    [MKMapItem openMapsWithItems:@[mapItem] launchOptions:nil];
```

You can add the options dictionary as you want to the launchOptions.

If you want to get lat long from the string, use geocoder

```
CLGeocoder().geocodeAddressString(txtSearchField.text!, completionHandler: { (placemarks, error) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                if let placemark = placemarks!.first {
                       let noLocation:CLLocationCoordinate2D =  placemark.location!.coordinate


                                                 }
                             } })
```

Comment: equivalent in objective-c?

Comment: Wrong location. It doesnt work. The location which you gave, seems constant.

Comment: Yes it is the constant location you will need to change CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(40, 0); to your dynamic value

Comment: I have no location value. I have just address in string

Comment: What is your address? I mean lat lng or name of place.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I found answer.

I used this :

```
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringwithformat:@"http://maps.apple.com/?address=%@", address];
     NSURL* mapURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[urlString 
stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

        if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:phoneURL]) {
                [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:phoneURL];
            }
```

Finally, I decide to don't use apple maps. Because it doesn't locate the location completely. I will use google maps url.